# Ruby syntax inside a heredoc?

Tags: ruby

I want to iterate an array inside a Ruby heredoc.

```
<<-BLOCK
Feature: User logs in
  In order to post content
  As an user
  I want to log in

<< Here i want to iterate scenarios >>
BLOCK
```

"scenarios" is an array I want to loop. For each element I want to print out:

```
Scenario: #{scenario}
  Given
  When
  Then
```

So for example if "scenarios" contains:

```
scenarios[0] = "User successfully logs in"
scenarios[1] = "User failed to log in"
```

I want the heredoc string to be:

```
<<-BLOCK
Feature: #{feature}
  In order to #{in_order_to}
  As #{as}
  I want #{i_want}

Scenario: User successfully logs in
  Given
  When
  And

Scenarios: User failed to log in
  Given
  When
  And
BLOCK
```

How do I do iterate inside a Ruby heredoc?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You *can* do it but I'm not sure it is the most readable approach:

```
s = <<-BLOCK
Feature: User logs in
  In order to post content
  As an user
  I want to log in

#{scenarios.map{|x|
<<-INNERBLOCK
Scenario: #{x}
  Given
  When
  Then
INNERBLOCK
}}

BLOCK
```

Comment: Why does it defeats the purpose of heredocs? Isn't it ok to be able to have dynamic data inside heredocs?

Comment: Btw. that didn't work cause \n was interpreted as text and not new line.

Comment: Weird. I still got the \n. Here is what the script and file looks like: http://pastie.org/1150945

Comment: @ajsie: That looks right to me. Try using `puts` or `print` on an element of the list to see the real value of the string.

Answer (score 18):

You could use ERB. It would be cleaner and not that much more code:

```
require 'erb'
s = ERB.new(<<-BLOCK).result(binding)
Feature: User logs in
  In order to post content
  As an user
  I want to log in

<% scenarios.map do |x| %>
  Scenario: <%= x %>
  Given
  When
  Then
<% end %>
BLOCK
```

The first line might look weird, so I'll break it down

```
s = ERB.new(<<-BLOCK).result(binding)
```

`ERB.new` creates a new erb template with the passed string as its content. `<<-BLOCK` is a heredoc that says take the heredoc value that follows and sub it into the expression. `result(binding)` Evaluates the template in the current context(`binding` being the context of the current evaluation).

From there you can easily extract your templates into files as they get bigger.

[More about Ruby's heredocs by James Edward Gray II](http://graysoftinc.com/ruby-voodoo/working-with-multiline-strings)

Comment: this is a better solution, IMHO